# Matching demographics from two tables with no unique identifiers

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have Table A and Table B with the following sample demographics data and columns.

Table A:

```
F_Name  S_Name  DOB         SSN
David   Sam     1/1/1980    123-45-6789
David   Lieser  10/7/1940   987-65-4321
John    Doe     12/31/2001  500-00-0000
```

Table B:

```
F_Name  S_Name  DOB      SSN
Dave    Sammy   1/2/1980 223-45-6789
```

There are no unique identifiers to potentially use to join the two tables.

By looking at the above sample data, I’d like to return **David Sam 1/1/1980 123-45-6789** (from Table A) and **Dave Sammy 1/2/1980 223-455-6789** (from Table B) as potentially the same people – the rationale is that the DOB, SSNs are close enough with one or a couple digits off perhaps due to human data entry error and the names sound similar or are similar enough or identical. How can I achieve this?

```
F_Name S_Name DOB      SSN          F_Name_1 S_Name_1  DOB_1    SSN_1
David  Sam    1/1/1980 123-45-6789  Dave     Sammy     1/2/1980 223-455-6789
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jaro-Winkler similarity might help. Have a look at the following example:

```
SQL> with
  2  table_a (fname, sname, dob, ssn) as
  3    (select 'David', 'Sam'   , date '1980-01-01', '123-45-6789' from dual union all
  4     select 'David', 'Lieser', date '1940-10-07', '987-65-4321' from dual union all
  5     select 'John' , 'Doe'   , date '2001-12-31', '500-00-0000' from dual
  6    ),
  7  table_b (fname, sname, dob, ssn) as
  8    (select 'Dave', 'Sammy'  , date '1980-01-02', '223-45-6789' from dual
  9    )
 10  select a.fname, a.sname, a.dob, a.ssn,
 11         b.fname, b.sname, b.dob, b.ssn,
 12    utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(a.fname, b.fname) jws_fname,
 13    utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(a.sname, b.sname) jws_sname,
 14    utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(to_char(a.dob, 'yyyymmdd'), to_char(b.dob, 'yyyymmdd')) jws_dob,
 15    utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(a.ssn, b.ssn) jws_ssn
 16  from table_a a cross join table_b b
 17  where
 18        utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(a.fname, b.fname) >= 80
 19    and utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(a.sname, b.sname) >= 80
 20    and utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(to_char(a.dob, 'yyyymmdd'), to_char(b.dob, 'yyyymmdd')) >= 80
 21    and utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(a.ssn, b.ssn) >= 80;

FNAME SNAME  DOB      SSN         FNAM SNAME DOB      SSN          JWS_FNAME  JWS_SNAME    JWS_DOB    JWS_SSN
----- ------ -------- ----------- ---- ----- -------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
David Sam    01.01.80 123-45-6789 Dave Sammy 02.01.80 223-45-6789         84         90         95      93

SQL>
```

I set the limit to **80**, but you might decide differently. Remove the `WHERE` clause (lines #17 - 21) and check the results returned, then you'll have a clearer idea of what's going on.

Comment: Upvoted.  I would wager, though, that using `utl_match.edit_distance` would be more appropriate on the SSN and DOB.  Jaro Winkler and related string matching algorithms take advantage of the fact that typos/ variations in names are more likely to come at the end of the string (Sam vs Sammy) rather than at the beginning (Sam vs Ram).  The same is unlikely to be true for things like SSN and DOB where the data entry operator is (probably) equally likely to have errors on any digit.

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot and the rest! could the above be improved if one of the tables has over 1 million records while the other several thousand? Performance seems to be badly affected when using JW similarity on large tables.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, the problem you have requires measures that aren't popular nor fast. Any kind of such a comparison promises to be slow. Maybe it can be improved, but I don't know how. Sorry.